# RSpec Book - Unexpected Pending behavior

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm working in the RSpec book and I'm having "interesting" results with pending

Here's the code from the book (page 119 in my copy)

```
context "with 1 exact match duplicated in guess" do
    it "returns 0" do
        pending("refactor number_match_count")
        marker = Marker.new('1234','1155')
        marker.number_match_count.should == 0
    end
end
```

This code used to provide a rspec comment that the test was "pending"
but now it shows up as an error.

```
with 1 exact match duplicated in guess
returns 0 (FAILED - 1)
```

But if I move the "pending line up to before the "returns 0" line I get "expected" results, so the following code

```
context "with 1 exact match duplicated in guess" do
    pending("refactor number_match_count")
    it "returns 0" do
        #pending("refactor number_match_count")
        marker = Marker.new('1234', '1155')
        marker.number_match_count.should == 0
    end
end
```

yields "expected" results

```
with 1 exact match duplicated in guess
    refactor number_match_count (PENDING: Not yet implemented)
    returns 0
```

Why do I get an error with the pending in one place but not the other.

Possibly the weirdest thing is that the code now works, I only noticed this when I was going back to pull the pending out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec 3.1?  Pending's meaning has changed...

From: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples

> An example can either be marked as skipped, in which is it not
>   executed, or pending in which it is executed but failure will not
>   cause a failure of the entire suite. When a pending example passes
>   (i.e. the underlying reasons for it being marked pending is no longer
>   present) it will be marked as failed in order to communicate to you
>   that it should no longer be marked as pending.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.